# How can I Kill Executor process in spark from Driver

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to kill on of the executor process from spark  driver , how can I achieve this

I am getting the executor process id from spark rest service

Comment: The real question here is _why_ are you trying to kill one of the executors processes?

Comment: want to implement chaos monkey feature in spark code this just testing purpose of my code , if in real scenario so one the executor process killed how the program is gooing to behave or work

Comment: I see. Well, this is not something that is supported by Spark, so you will have to kill the process from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

In latest Spark versions one can use:

**Scala**

`sparkContext.killExecutors(Seq("your exec id from Spark UI"))`

**Python**

`spark.sparkContext().killExecutors(["YOUR ID"])`

Answer (score -2):

You can type `jps` first to get the process ID, then use `kill ID` on the command line.

Comment: the process will be ran after kill